# SDP Downloader gives error 10060 when downloading Windows Media

Tags: download, wmv, mms-streaming

SDP Downloader gives error 10060 when downloading Windows Media (WMV, ASX...). Playback on Windows Media Player works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 10060 means timeout. If the stream works correctly in Windows Media Player, it's likely the server doesn't support the selected protocol.

Try changing the protocol:

1. In SDP Downloader, go to `Setup | Setup Options`.
2. Switch to the `Protocol` tab.
3. Try one of the other protocols. **HTTP** is your preferred option (unless HTTP is the option that failed), then **TCP**, then **UDP** as a last resort.